# Is there a way to enable face tracking with rear (back) camera with AR Foundation/ARKit (Unity)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore, face

I'm trying to create an AR app which uses AR Foundation face tracking. Unfortunately, face tracking seems to be supported on the front camera (selfie) only (TrueDepth, Lidar etc).

I found it that it also can track faces on a photo or screen (which is a flat picture). So, in theory, it still should be possible to use a back camera for face tracking. Is there way to workaround the front-camera-only restriction? I understand that it may be bad in terms of performance and quality, but I'd like to check how bad it is (if it's possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, a possible workaround would be to extract frames captured by the rear camera and use something like [OpenCV for Unity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-for-unity-21088) to analyze the images and detect faces.